# Invite users to facebook group

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Users that login to my site for the first time via facebook connect are redirect to a php script which should invite them to my societies facebook group.

```
<?php
require_once "facebook_sdk/src/facebook.php";

$app_id = 'xxxxxxx';
$app_secret = 'xxxxxxx';

// Init facebook api.
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId' => $app_id,
    'secret' => $app_secret,
    'cookie' => true
));

// Get the url to redirect for login to facebook
$login_url = $facebook->getLoginUrl(
    array('scope' => 'manage_pages')
);

// If not authenticated, redirect to the facebook login dialog.
// The $login_url will take care of redirecting back to us
// after successful login.
if (! $facebook->getUser()) {
    echo <<< EOT
<script type="text/javascript">
top.location.href = "$login_url";
</script>;
EOT;

    exit;
}

$token=$facebook->getAccessToken();
echo $token . "</br>";
$user=$facebook->getUser();
$page = "/45277909073/members/" . $user . "/";
echo $page;

$facebook->api($page, "post",array('access_token='=>$token));
?>
```

this code outputs the following 
173863136082149|9f42756f3760ff697b3c4e809bfe48f7
/45277909073/members/987654321/
**Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: A user access token is required to request this resource. thrown in /home/somewhere/public_html/fb/facebook_sdk/src/base_facebook.php on line 1238**

Ive based this on the doku under invite user section 
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/group/

Answer (score 1):

in

```
'access_token=' => $token
```

it should be

```
'access_token' => $token
```